# "Pluralsight Skill IQ assessment" asking me to create an account

Tags: support, pluralsight-iq

I was going to do take the Pluralsight Skill IQ assessment, it said its free but when i provided the information and agreed on terms, i was redirected to login / create account on pluralsight and when i attempt to create an account it asks me to pay.

Comment: Tried it just now. Works perfectly.

Comment: No repro, pluralsight doesnt ask you to pay unless you want to take a couse.

Comment: just as an FYI: you will need to pay if you want to take the test more than twice. To take it more than twice, you need to complete a certain line of courses. Those courses cost money.

Comment: When i fill my email and agree on terms i get this message: "Redeeming Your Benefit
Attempting to activate your benefit (this may take a few seconds)" then i am redirected to sign in /up page... and since i dont have an account on plural sight, i click on create account and here is where it gives the prices.

Comment: I was able to perform the test by creating a new free trial account but while doing the test for two questions the page freeze and my answers were considered as wrong.

Comment: same problem here. not able add or edit my skill iq